# print an array list in a list format in java w/o a loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, printing

I am trying to re-define the method toString(), which has to return a String, to print an array list called cards with type Card. Because toString() has to return a string I can't use a loop to print out each element one by one, yet I want to print the array list in a list format. Basically, does anyone know how to make toString() return the array list cards as a string without using a loop?

cards array list definition

```
    ArrayList <Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

Card class creator

```
    Card card1 = new Card(String suit, String rank, int value);
```

toString method

```
    public String deckToString(){
        return cards;
    }
```

What it should print

```
[suit, rank, value]
[suit, rank, value]
[suit, rank, value]
[suit, rank, value]
 etc.
```

What it currently prints

```
[suit, rank, value] [suit, rank, value] etc.
```

Comment: "Because toString() has to return a string I can't use a loop," eh? Why do you think you can't use a loop in a method returning a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
you want each value on its own line.
In other words, join the values by a line break, instead of by comma.

```
public String deckToString() {
    return String.join("\n", cards.stream().map(Card::toString).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: This works great thanks! Could you just elaborate more on what this is doing? Just curious.

Comment: Sure. It converts the list of cards to a list of strings, by mapping each using their `toString` method. Finally, it joins all the strings by `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public String deckToString(){
            temp="";
            for (int i = 0;i<cards.length;i++){
                  temp+=cards.get(i)+"\n";
            return temp;
  }
```

This simply iterates through the cards and adds a newline for each card and adds it to the return string. This is similar to janos solution but is more visually simple.